# How to Display items on demand on ListView/Datagrid with vertical scrollbar with mouse up and down using Wpf MVVM?

Tags: wpf

I have a listview which have can say 80+ records and each record have 7 images. When i display whole records then it take too much time and also consuming memory.
I want to design wpf control, which display only records which can viewable on the page (suppose to be 6 records with assigned space). Suppose When user clicks on middle part of the scrollbar at position 50 then i have to show record from 45 to 50.
please help me by giving any sample tutorial,references or by code.

thanks
Ghacho

Answer (score 1):

ListViews and DataGrids are virtualized (create controls only when visible) by default, you just need to use [data-binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data-templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) instead of adding all the items manually (and thus forcing their creation).

Comment: thanks H.B, actually i m newbei in wpf. would you please provide any example or code sample.

Comment: thanks H.B i have solved this issues by using Data Virtualization..now i m having another issue..I am using images control which are windowsformshost controls in my listbox, but when scroll down or up..it exceeds from the listbox boundry.. I can't bind windowsformshost into datatemplate..can i use them in codebehind or is there any other way to solve this issue..thanks

Comment: That question is material for another separate question, i have never used WindowsFormsHosts before...